# Find and replace all occurrences of a substring in C

Tags: c, string, replace

I am trying to find and replace all occurrences of a substring within an array of strings in C. I think I have most of the logic down, however I dont know where I am messing up for the remaining parts.

Here is the relevant code - the string I am replacing is in `searchStr` and I am trying to replace it with `replaceStr`. The array of strings is called `buff`. I do not need to save the modified string back into the array after, I just need to print the modified string to the console.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        char *tmp = buff[i];
        char finalStr[MAX_STR_LEN * 2];
        char temporaryString[MAX_STR_LEN];
        int match = 0;
        while ((tmp = strstr(tmp, searchStr))) {
            match = 1;
            char temporaryString[MAX_STR_LEN];
            char tmp2[MAX_STR_LEN];
            printf("Buff[i]: %s", buff[i]);

            sprintf(temporaryString, "%s", strstr(tmp, searchStr) + strlen(searchStr)); // Grab everything after the match
            printf("Behind: %s", temporaryString);

            strncpy(tmp2, buff[i], tmp - buff[i]); // Grab everything before the match
            strcat(finalStr, tmp2);
            printf("In Front: %s\n", finalStr);

            strcat(finalStr, replaceStr); // Concat everything before with the replacing string

            tmp = tmp + strlen(searchStr);
            buff[i] = tmp; // Move buff pointer up so that it looks for another match in the remaining part of the string
        }
        if (match) {
            strcat(finalStr, temporaryString); // Add on any remaining bytes
            printf("Final: %s\n", finalStr); 
        }
    }
```

If have a lot of `printf` in there just so I can see where everything is for debugging.

**Example case:**

If I am running it against the string `what4is4this` with `searchStr = 4` and `replaceStr = !!!` this is the output in the console... I am adding annotations as well using `//`

```
Buff[i]: what4is4this           // Just printing out the current string before we attempt to replace anything
Behind: is4this                 // Looking good here
In Front: hat                   // Why is it cutting off the 'w'? 
Buff[i]: is4this                // Good - this is the remaining string we need to look through
Behind: this                    // Again, looking good
In Front: hat!!!isat            // It should be 'is'
Final: hat!!!isat!!!isat        // final should be 'what!!!is!!!this'
```

Any ideas guys? Im tearing my hair out trying to fix this

Thanks!

Comment: You should get the replacement working in one string, before you attempt to iterate over an array of strings, and you have been on this site long enough to know about [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note: `finalString` seems to be uninitialised. and `temporaryString` shadows ... `temporaryString` ... And `strlen(searchStr)` and `strlen(replaceStr)` are loop-invariant, I hope.

Comment: Initialize `finalStr` to an empty string, so you can concatenate to it properly. `char finalStr[MAX_STR_LEN*2] = "";`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/VseXsD

Comment: Start with more descriptive names than "temporaryString", "tmp" and "tmp2".  Then your bugs will be more clearly seen.  For one thing, strstr always searches in searchStr, which never changes, so it should always return the same thing. Obviously it is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is an unhealthy mix of pointer-juggling and undefined behavior, but the commenters already told you that. If you simplify it a bit and make good and frugal use of pointers you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

#define MAX_STR_LEN 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *buff, *cpbuff;
  char *searchStr;
  char *replaceStr;

  // pointers too the two parts with the search string in between
  char *tmp, *after;
  // the final output (a fixed length is not good, 
  // should be dynamically allocated)
  char finalStr[MAX_STR_LEN * 2] = { '\0' };

  if (argc < 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string searchstr replacestr\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  buff = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  strcpy(buff, argv[1]);
  searchStr = malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
  strcpy(searchStr, argv[2]);
  replaceStr = malloc(strlen(argv[3]) + 1);
  strcpy(replaceStr, argv[3]);

  // Keep a finger on the start of buff
  cpbuff = buff;
  while (1) {
    printf("Buff: %s\n", buff);
    // Grab everything after the match
    after = strstr(buff, searchStr);
    // No further matches? Than we're done
    if (after == NULL) {
      strcat(finalStr, buff);
      break;
    }
    // assuming strlen(searchStr) >= 1
    tmp = buff;
    // mark the end of the first part
    tmp[after - buff] = '\0';
    // set the after pointer to the start of the second part
    after = after + strlen(searchStr);
    printf("Behind: %s\n", after);
    printf("Before: %s\n\n", tmp);
    // Put the first part to it's final place
    strcat(finalStr, tmp);
    // concat the replacement string
    strcat(finalStr, replaceStr);
    // Set buff to the start of the second part
    buff = after + strlen(searchStr) - 1;
  }
  printf("Final: %s\n", finalStr);
  // set the buff pointer back to it's start
  buff = cpbuff;

  free(buff);
  free(searchStr);
  free(replaceStr);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The single point that can be called an abuse of pointer arithmetic is the line that marks the end of the first part. It can be avoided by measuring and using the lengths of the involved strings and do arithmetic with them. It is slower, admitted, so it depends on your individual use case.

It is still more complicated than I like it, but it's a start.

I hope you can extend it now to several lines of input by yourself.